# Sed Pattern filtering long html doc

Tags: sed

I am trying to filter a long html page, for leaving only fingerprints which have a consistent structure. for example:

> DCD0 5B71 EAB9 4199 527F 44AC DB6B 8C1F 96D8 BF60

i know how to do it by using standrd command line commands as grep, cut and head/tail, but is there more elegant way to do it with sed? the shell comman i use is long and not looking so nice.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` is the right tool for extracting strings from a file based on regular expression matching:

```
grep -Eo '([A-F0-9]{4}[[:space:]]){9}[A-F0-9]{4}' file.html
```

Comment: thanks for that!
now the question is - i am trying to assignt the results to variables, but this is not working for me. 
is the only way saving it to some temp file and then read line by line?

Comment: You don't need a tempfile, you can pipe directly to `while read`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sed command tested with GNU sed 4.2.2:

```
sed -nr '/(([[:xdigit:]]){4} ?){10}/p' file
```

It matches and prints

- 10 groups that are made of

  - 4 hexdigits
  - followed by an optional space

Comment: Nicely done, but while it _matches_ what you describe, it _prints_ the _full lines_.

Comment: @mklement, you are right, my test case was too simple.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/.*(([A-F0-9]{4}[[:space:]]){9}[A-F0-9]{4}).*/\1/' file
```

Comment: Which OS and sed version do you use?

Comment: Cent OS 7.
Sed 4.2.2

Comment: Sorry, I can not reproduce this. This works fine with RHEL 7 and GNU sed version 4.2.2: `echo 'dlkdlfkd DCD0 5B71 EAB9 4199 527F 44AC DB6B 8C1F 96D8 BF60 ssd' | sed -E 's/.*(([A-F0-9]{4}[[:space:]]){9}[A-F0-9]{4}).*/\1/'`